# Swift Package Manager link shared archive library on MacOS

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, swift-package-manager

I have a swift package manager library with multiple targets and one product.

Its `Package.swift` looks something like this:

```swift
let package = Package(
    name: "FooPackage",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "FooLibrary",
            targets: ["FooLibrary"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "FooHeaders"),
        .target(
            name: "FooLibrary",
            dependencies: [
                "FooHeaders"
            ],
            path: nil,
            exclude: [],
            sources: nil,
            resources: nil,
            publicHeadersPath: "include",
            cSettings: nil,
            cxxSettings: nil,
            swiftSettings: nil,
            linkerSettings: [
                .linkedLibrary("/path/to/libfoo.a")
            ]
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "FooTests",
            dependencies: [
                "FooHeaders",
                "FooLibrary"
            ],
            path: nil,
            exclude: [],
            sources: nil,
            cSettings: nil, cxxSettings: nil, swiftSettings: nil,
            linkerSettings: nil)
    ]
)
```

I also have a directory structure that looks like this:

- FooPackage

  - Libraries

    - libfoo.a
  - Sources

    - FooHeaders

      - include

        - some_header_files.h
    - FooLibrary

      - SomeSwiftFiles.swift (these call a bunch of the methods exposed in the header files)
  - Tests

    - FooTests

      - SomeTestFiles.swift

Now my issue is that whenever I run `swift test`, I get the following error message on Mac:

```
Building for debugging...
ld: library not found for -l/path/to/libfoo.a
[0/1] Linking FooTests
error: fatalError
```

Note that I specify the path to libfoo.a from root. Oddly enough, running `swift build` does work on Mac, though it seems that that is merely a compilation step, and does not do any linking.

However, when I compile the shared library on a Linux machine, be it physical or inside Docker, with everything else being exactly equal, there, `swift test` does work. That seems to be the case on both Debian and Ubuntu; I haven't tried testing other operating systems yet.

What could be going wrong, and what am I doing wrong? I have looked at a bunch of similar posts on StackOverflow, though nobody appears to have their project in a state where the compilation and running actually *does* work – just not on Mac. I would also like to stress that I am *not* using Xcode; instead, all of this is compiled straight from the command line.

Also, if that's any help, the shared library is compiled from a Rust project. I simply run `cargo build` and copy the library inside `target/debug` into the `Libraries` folder in my project, whereto the path is specified in `Package.swift`.

Some things I tried doing was using the same linker settings in both the standard target, as well as the test target. I also tried using the .dylib extension on Mac instead of .a (`cargo build` generates both), as well as removing the file extension altogether, and I have also tried various experiments with specifying the path relative to the root folder of the project, and various folders within it. So far, all to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have figured it out, and the solution is as follows.

In `Package.swift`, add this snippet in the beginning:

```swift
var linkerSettings: [PackageDescription.LinkerSetting] = [.linkedLibrary("/path/to/libfoo.a")]
#if os(macOS)
    linkerSettings = [
        .unsafeFlags(["-L/path/to/"]),
        .linkedLibrary("foo")
    ]
#endif
```

And then, where it used to say

```swift
linkerSettings: [
    .linkedLibrary("/path/to/libfoo.a")
]
```

replace that code with

```swift
linkerSettings: linkerSettings
```

instead.